# How to implement a Singleton / Monostate Instance with Ember Components

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

If you want to introduce a layer of indirection on the component level -- i.e. declaratively -- how would you do that?
I'm not aware of any possibility to do this in a declarative manner with Ember.
You could do `getElementById()` but with this you can only grab the DOM output and not the component instance.

To make my question more tangible, an example:
Say you have component A that has a configurable behaviour that you don't want to define over-and-over again through an attribute. So the component may do a lookup on a key like `meta.A.configSetting` to see whether there the `configSetting` has been set globally.

Polymer has a component called ['polymer-meta'](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-meta) for this. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799277/1821792) an illustration how it can be used.
You also place component AX in your app which happens to provider a specific value for this config key (and probably for many others) in a [monostate](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern) manner.

Speaking more generally, with Polymer you can plumb things together by passing ID's of DOM elements around that you can lookup and use as normal JS objects. I think this is nice and I don't see any equivalent in Ember.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a service?

Comment: You could register the component to a factory - that way you have a reference as a singleton